# Google Sheets Countif function does not highlight the whole row

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets-formula

The Condition formatting 'Countif' did not highlight the whole row even adding $.

```
=Countif($H$3:$H$9,H3)>1
```

[image: 1]

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply to range: `H3:I10`

Formula: `=Countif($H$3:$H$10,$H3)>1`